# Cannot autowire argument $request

Tags: php, symfony, http, autowired, psr-7

My controller looks like:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class HelloController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request): Response
    {
        dd($request)
        return $this->json([]);
    }
```

After going to URL of this controller I get the following error:

```
Cannot autowire argument $request of "HelloController()": it references interface "Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

My composer.json looks like:

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.1",
        "psr/http-client": "^1.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.1",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/messenger": "^4.1",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.1",
        "php-http/httplug": "^2.0",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5"
    },
```

I have not set anything in `services.yaml` file.

Comment: Interesting.  Did not realize the bridge was still around.  It never did get used much.  The examples I have seen used the zendframework/zend-diactoros package.  Don't know if the PsrServerRequestParamConverter needs some configuration for the nyholm package.  You should probably do yourself a favor and at least use Symfony 4.4.

Comment: It's weird because on Symfony toolbar it shows that I have Symfony 4.4, but in `composer.json`, it says that I have 4.1 LOL Do you know why?

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that you are looking at one directory but running code from another.  It happens.  You seem to have a very short list of dependencies.  Consider creating a fresh 4.4 project, install the bridge and the nyholm packages and see if that works.

Comment: ... and, if not, install the package `"psr/http-message": "^1.0",` as well and try again.

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpFoundation` request object to PSR7 `ServerRequestInterface` implementation conversion was performed by `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle`.

But the [support was removed](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/commit/503c29d3cb7cf477513ea6e8620dd2e98a930e5f) in `v6`

Either downgrade to `v5.5` or switch to alternative.

The following bundle provides the removed feature and is based on the original implementation.

https://github.com/ajgarlag/psr-http-message-bundle

Answer (score -1):

This is how you'd retrieve the request stack on Symfony 4.x version.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class HelloController 
{      

  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
  {
      $request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
  }

}
```

The above was extracted from here:- https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/request.html

Comment: The question was about retrieving a PSR-7 based request object.  Not the Symfony one.  When properly configured the message bridge does just that.  I might add that using the request stack to retrieve the current request in a constructor will often fail miserably.